# What to call a small restaurant which serves only a single type of food?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, food

In my location, there are many small restaurants that each serve only a single type of food, e.g., noodles, noodle soup,... mainly noodles but only 1 single type.

It's not a café, not a cafeteria, not a restaurant (many types of foods), not a stall because it's in a house,...

Should it be called a "noodle shop"?

Comment: "Noodle shop" is fine I'd say. Google ngrams shows usage since 1980. Other answers can give you synonym options for elegant variation.

Comment: I'm thinking I've heard a term similar to "bodega", but I can't recall it.

Comment: @HotLicks Do you mean "boutique"? Like "bodega", it can be traced back to a Latin word for “storehouse” (apotheca)

Comment: @auspicious99 - No, it was something catchier.

Comment: If 'hole-in-the-wall [restaurant]' is accepted as an answer (no requirement of 'selling only one type of food'), then this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this precisely hits your definition, but a [hole-in-the-wall restaurant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hole-in-the-wall) refers to the *size* and inconspicuousness of a restaurant.

That's not the same as having a limited menu, but hole-in-the-wall restaurants are often exactly those that have a strong focus on their specialty menus.

Answer (score 3):

You could describe the place as a ***boutique restaurant***.

Merriam-Webster's second [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boutique) of boutique is:

> a small company that offers highly specialized services or products
>
> > boutique wineries
>
> > an independent investment boutique

This word has both the connotation of smallness, as well as the highly specialized product which the single type of food would represent.

Comment: Thus is a much better answer than the hole in the wall one.

Comment: Thanks @Kris ; I think I wrote my answer 1 day after the other answer, which meanwhile had gotten the votes. Anyway, hope my answer is helpful to someone in the future.